# Swift 2.1 Core Data - updating image record with setValue()

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to update data on an existing record with the following

```
...

recipeToUpdate.setValue(recipe.title, forKey: "image")
recipeToUpdate.setValue(recipe.setRecipeImage(recipeImg.image!), forKey: "image")

...
```

The first parameter for `setValue` is value and for the title it's simple as `recipe.title` but for saving image, I have a custom function `setRecipeImage()` which is used for creating a new record for NSData

```
func setRecipeImage(img: UIImage) {
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    self.image = data
}
```

I believe I need a function like this to update image record and I'm not sure how I use it as a parameter of `setValue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity name is `recipeToUpdate`?

`recipeToUpdate.setValue(UIImagePNGRepresentation(recipeImg.image!), forKey: "image")`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to write image data in the app's file dictionary?

That means saving image as a file. And you can save the image file's url as `String` to `CoreData` so that you just simply replace old file with new file in order to update.

Whenever you need to fetch image data , you can get the url from `Coredata` and fetch the image from url.